# Trying to write to a MySQL database with a PHP form

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms

I'm trying to do a simple write to database with an HTML form, using PHP.

I've run the SQL query in the database and it works perfectly. However, using the form doesn't work. I'm not sure why. Any help? The user/pass/db name are all correct.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","delives0_ideas","ideas");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("delives0_ideas", $con);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO data (firstName, lastName, email, idea) VALUES ('$_POST['firstName']','$_POST['lastName']', '$_POST['email']', '$_POST['idea']')");

//also email it to us besides writing it into the database

mysql_close($con);
?>

<form method="post">
<strong>First name:</strong> <input type="text" name="firstName"/>
<br/>
<strong>Last name:</strong> <input type="text" name="lastName"/>
<br/>
<strong>Email:</strong> <input type="text" name="email"/>  #####Put a javascript checker for valid emails, like name@site.com format
<br/>
<br/>
<strong>Idea:</strong>
<br/>
<textarea rows="10" cols="30" name="idea"> 
Hit us with your best shot.
</textarea> 
<br/>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Does the mysql_query return true or false? Also, could this be a permissions issue?

Comment: Please if you are not using PDO then at least make use of http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php for your own good :)

Comment: *Sigh* — http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: I'm not sure if it returns true or false but the SQL portion works fine as I stated. And I gave the user in question all possible permissions so it shouldn't be an issue like that.

Comment: I've sanitized the inputs, thanks a lot, forgot about that. I haven't done this in years.

Comment: please do not put a javascript check for valid emails.  there's a 100% chance that you will get it wrong.  RFC2822 (the email address spec) is very very complicated.  There is a regex that's over 7000 characters long that matches only 98% of all valid addresses.  You don't want to do that in javascript.

Just having an @ does not make a valid email address, in fact some valid email addresses do not have an @

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the "action = nameofyourpage.php" inside the form markup. And I would add a "or die (mysql_error())" at the end of your query to check the syntax of the request.

Comment: That worked, thank you. How would I go about sending an email to a certain email address containing the values pulled from the form, in addition to putting them into the database?

Answer (score 2):

you've got a few errors in your script - please check the following

http://pastie.org/1056569

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
   $con = mysql_connect("localhost","delives0_ideas","ideas");
   if (!$con){
     die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

   mysql_select_db("delives0_ideas", $con);

   $sqlCmd = sprintf("INSERT INTO data (firstName, lastName, email, idea) 
     VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s')", 
      mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["firstName"]),
      mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["lastName"]),
      mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]),
      mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["idea"]));

   mysql_query($sqlCmd);
   mysql_close($con);
 }
 ?>

 <form method="post">
  <strong>First name:</strong> <input type="text" name="firstName"/><br/>
  <strong>Last name:</strong> <input type="text" name="lastName"/><br/>
  <strong>Email:</strong> <input type="text" name="email"/> 
  <strong>Idea:</strong><br/>
  <textarea rows="10" cols="30" name="idea">Hit us with your best shot.</textarea><br/>
  <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
 </form>
```

Comment: Please post code snippets here. Your answer will be meaningless if the external site goes away...

Answer (score 0):

You already have the answer to your question as to why it was not working, but please check this [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) about SQL injection attacks before putting this code into production.

Answer (score 0):

you have error

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO data (firstName, lastName, email, idea) VALUES
('$_POST['firstName']','$_POST['lastName']', '$_POST['email']', '$_POST['idea']')");
```

Error = '$_POST['firstName']' you have chatter ' in post field

and you can change

```
 $firstname = $_POST['firstName'];
 $lastname = $_POST['lastName'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $idea = $_POST['idea'];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO data (firstName, lastName, email, idea) VALUES ('{$firstname}','{$lastname}', '{$email}', '{$idea}')");
```

or with mysql query

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO data SET firstName='{$firstname}', lastName='{$lastname}',
email='{$email}', idea='{$idea}'");
```